# Viewmodel object does not receive database source changes

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm

New to WPF, MVVM, data binding, and Entity Framework, so apologies in advance.

I'm attempting to bind WPF controls to my database-generated model objects through a viewmodel. I'm able to change database values by typing in the textbox, but any direct changes to the database rows do not seem to fire off the PropertyChanged event. At least they are not reflected in my viewmodel objects. I've implemented iNotifyPropertyChanged on my Entity Framework generated classes thus:

```
    public partial class GenGround : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public double ClMax
        {
            get { return (double)this.clMax; }
            set 
            {
                this.clMax = (float)value;
                MainWindow.db.SaveChanges();
                OnPropertyChanged("ClMax");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string Property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a listbox:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="missionLegTemplate">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
     </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<ListBox x:Name="missionList" SelectionChanged="missionList_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource missionLegTemplate}" />


    private void MainWindow1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.missionList.ItemsSource = _CurrentMissionProfile.MissionLegs;
    }
```

"MissionLegs" is an ObservableCollection of MissionLeg objects, attached to the database. The selected item of this listbox should tell the textboxes what properties to get and set. Textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="velocityBox" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay,Path=SelectedItem.Velocity, ElementName=missionList}" IsEnabled="False" />
```

As I said, this seems to write to the database, but when I make changes to the corresponding row in SSMS, nothing seems to happen. Ideas?

Comment: you do not requery the database after changing the value in ssms, therefore the viewmodel does not get updated, and in turn, your view.  The value of the field must be updated in your viewmodel before it can update the view.

Comment: So would I have to set-up a background thread to constantly monitor changes to the database? I thought that's what I would be avoiding with data-binding...

Comment: Data binding will bind your textbox to the velocity property on an object, but updating the DB outside of the application, does not update the bound object.  are you looking for recommendations on how to handle an outside DB update, and reflect that in a bound object?

Comment: Yes, the context is in a multi-user synchronous environment. Multiple clients are making edits, I'm guessing the PropertyChanged event doesn't go past the client where it is generated?